# What is the role of feature type in AzureML?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, code-documentation

I want to know what is the difference between `feature numeric` and `numeric` columns in Azure Machine Learning Studio.

The [documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/edit-metadata) states:

> Because all columns are initially treated as features, for modules
>   that perform mathematical operations, you might need to use this
>   option to prevent numeric columns from being treated as variables.

But nothing more. Not what a feature is, in which modules you need features. Nothing.

I specifically would like to understand if the `clear feature` dropdown option in the `fields` in the `edit metadata`-module has any effect. Can somebody give me a szenario where this `clear feature`-operation changes the ML outcome? Thank you

According to the documentation in ought to have an effect:

> Use the Fields option if you want to change the way that Azure Machine
>   Learning uses the data in a model.

But what can this effect be? Any example might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, setting a column as `feature` does have an effect, and it's actually quite important - when training a model, the algorithms will only take into account columns with the `feature` flag, effectively ignoring the others.

For example, if you have a dataset with columns `Feature1`, `Feature2`, and `Label` and you want to try out just `Feature1`, you would apply `clear feature` to the `Feature2` column (while making sure that `Feature1` has the `feature` label set, of course).

Comment: Thanks that explains the concept. Because in my model there were two variables set as non-features. It didn't make any difference whether to include them or not. I suppose it is because AzureML's logistic regression algorithm does some sort of feature selection.

Comment: It may be that they're not important enough - you can check out their weights by visualizing the output port of the Train Model module, and see how they look in either feature/non-feature scenarios.